# vba excel passing parameter from sub to sub

Tags: vba

I want to pass my input to other subs,something like:

```
Sub Search()
  Inputbox myInput   '~> this is the variable I want to pass
  Call getInput      '~> I want to pass the variable to this sub
End sub

Sub getInput()
  if a = myInput     '~> from sub Search()
  DO something
End sub
```

I search for solution and read about ByVal or ByRef but i get confused where to put the variable, someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Search()
  Inputbox myInput   '~> this is the variable I want to pass
  Call getInput (myInput)  '~> Note the variable
End sub

Sub getInput(ByVal inputVar As String)  '~> Note:  You need to specify the datatype
  If a = inputVar Then     '~> Use your parameter here
      'DO something
  End If
End sub
```