# Find and replace a word from excel. application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
For each cl in rng
```

Getting Run-time error '1004':

```
Application-defined or object-defined error in 
**Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))**
```

Please help

Comment: Original code                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408568/find-and-replace-multiple-words-in-word-from-excel-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rory has already told you what the main problem with your code is.

I would recommend a slightly different approach to what you are trying to achieve.

Please note that `xlDown` should be avoided as much as possible. Consider the scenario where there is data only in cell `A1`. In such a case `xlDown` will select the entire Col A. The alternative is to find last row in Col A which has data and then create your range.

```
With ws
    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A and then create the range
    '~~> oXL is the Excel Application
    If oXL.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If

    Set Rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
End With
```

And declare this at the top

```
Const xlPart As Long = 2
Const xlFormulas As Long = -4123
Const xlByRows As Long = 1
Const xlPrevious As Long = 2
```

And if you are sure that there will always be data in Col A then you can try this as well

```
    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

And declare this at the top

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you don't have a reference set to the Excel object library in which case `xlDown` has no value. Either use:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(-4142))
```

or, preferably, define the constant yourself at the top of your module:

```
Const xlDown as Long = -4142
```

Comment: + 1 I suspect that is the case too :) However why xlDown and not xlup to create the range?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't know the layout of the workbook so just left it as it was. :)