# How to add to current cell selection in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a loop that checks every cell in a column and finds a specific date (currently the Monday of the previous week). My code right now does select them correctly but I want it to keep the previous selection so in the end all cells of that specification are selected

```
Public Function LastMonday(pdat As Date) As Date
        LastMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, pdat - (Weekday(pdat, vbMonday) - 1))
End Function

Sub Macro2()

 Macro2 Macro



Dim rng As Range
Dim curCellValue As String
Dim mondayStr As String

mondayStr = Format(LastMonday(Date), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Set rng = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("E2"), ActiveSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown))

For Each Cell In rng
    curCellValue = Cell.Value
    If curCellValue = mondayStr Then Cell.Select
Next Cell

End Sub
```

As a bonus, to change the Function to a different day of last week would I simply change the vbMonday to vbTuesday etc? I admit I don't know VBA very well and most of this is just frankensteined from around here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to do that is to store all the cells in a range using the `Union` Method.

Also I wouldn't recommend using `.Select`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Amend your code to add this code.

```
Dim MySel As Range

For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Value = mondayStr Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then
    With MySel
        '.Select
        '~~> Do something
    End With
End If
```

One more thing... Please note that `xlDown` should be avoided as much as possible. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759464/find-and-replace-a-word-from-excel-application-defined-or-object-defined-error/25760089#25760089)

Comment: Worked like a charm, also replaced the xlDown with the method suggested in your link.